# Nodejs fails to show output on the cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-server

I'm new to nodejs, All I'm trying to do is running a simple nodejs file on windows console Here's what I'm doing :

```js
const http = require('http');
const host = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });
  response.end('Hello world');
}).listen(port, host);

server.on('connect', function(req) {
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log('Connected!');
})

server.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
})
```

The file is stored on `D:\nodjs\test` directory when I navigate to this directory and run
the `node hello.js` command I'm expecting to see outputs ( response ) on the console.
However this is not happening, it just show a blank response, I wonder if it takes too long to load or anything else might be related with my client/port setup ?

[image: Here's a screenshot showing the case]

Comment: You're not saying that you are actually navigating with your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` to make a request. Are you? If not, your server is just sitting there waiting for requests.

Comment: you need to change `connect ` to `connection` and go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: Yea, I run the request on the browser, it's working now thanks @robertklep

Comment: @MohitSharma A client-side request needs to be sent, that's for sure. The choice of the event depends on the use case: `connect` in order to respond to an incoming http request, `connection` to respond to a TCP connection being established. Callbacks to serve content go with `connect`.